# How to recover specific table data from the binary log in mysql?

Tags: mysql, data-recovery, mysqlbinlog

Recently on my local test database, some of the tables got droped unfortunately by mistake.
I enables binary logging for that database.

I would like to get the data of those specific tables from the bindary logs.
how can i do this...?

I know that binary log will consist all the writes activty. but how to get the writes of that specifictable...? binary logs are of huge size(5GB each).

plese tell me if someone knows a better approach here..

Answer (score 0):

The best possible approach is to create a blackhole replication setup for the table you require.

It will log statements related to that table only.

In case of recovery you can simply use the binary logs of blackhole server to recover the data of that given table.